# How to create variable list of list of tuples from selected columns in dataframe?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, pandas

I have df that looks like this:

```
col1     col2      col3     col4
1         0         1        0 
1         0         1        0 
1         0         1        0 
1         0         1        0 
1         0         1        0
```

How do I convert `col1-col3` into a list of list of tuples and assign to variable? and then create an array of only col4 and assign to variable?

example final result:

```
lst = [[1,0,1],[1,0,1],[1,0,1],[1,0,1],[1,0,1]]]
lst_col4 = [[0],[0],[0],[0],[0]]
```

Comment: I don't see any tuple in your final result

Comment: df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3']].values.tolist()

Comment: You can select specific columns and then convert to a list of lists. See the marked duplicates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just index those coluns, and use the `.values` attribute:

```
lst = df[[col1, col2, col3]].values.tolist()
```

**Example:**

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[4,5,6], 'c':[7,8,9]})
>>> lst = df[['a', 'c']].values.tolist()
>>> print(lst)
 [[1, 7], [2, 8],[3, 9]]
```

Comment: this did it thank you!